# How can I put a theme for my SWT WPF program?

Tags: java, wpf, swt

I want use WPF on Windows version of my java application. I found it is easy to do it with SWT and it is also supporting wpf ResourceDictionary XAML for SWT elements ([please see this](http://robertmaldon.blogspot.com/2007/07/wpf-development-using-java-and-eclipse.html)). SWT WPF implementation working well for me but I couldn't find out how I can put [WPF theme](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes) on it. Some of SWT widgets same `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button` have `setData` method but some of them like `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display` have not that method. Also `setDate` method on `shell` will not set theme on entire window.

So how can I put a theme for entire window of my SWT WPF program?

Here is a sample code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;

public class MainForm {

    protected Shell shell;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MainForm window = new MainForm();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setData(
                "ResourceDictionary",
                "ExpressionDark.xaml");
        // theme not applied on entire window, just buttons

        shell.setSize(450, 300);
        shell.setText("Window Title");

        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.FLAT);
        button.setText("Button");
        button.setSize(250, 50);
        button.setBounds(0, 50, 250, 50);

        Menu menu = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
        shell.setMenuBar(menu);

        MenuItem mntmNewSubmenu = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.CASCADE);
        mntmNewSubmenu.setText("New SubMenu");

        Menu menu_1 = new Menu(mntmNewSubmenu);
        mntmNewSubmenu.setMenu(menu_1);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SWT WPF is no longer supported.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374569#c1) So it is better to not be used.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I have not used SWT WPF, so this may not work at all, but this is what you would typically do if you were using standard WPF

```
<Window 
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
    Template="{StaticResource WindowTemplateKey}">
</Window>
```

Where you would have a template something like this

```
<!-- Custom Window : to allow repositioning of ResizeGrip-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="WindowTemplateKey" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <Grid>
            <AdornerDecorator>
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </AdornerDecorator>
            <ResizeGrip Visibility="Collapsed" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="WindowResizeGrip" 
                        Style="{DynamicResource ResizeGripStyle1}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsTabStop="false"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip"/>
                <Condition Property="WindowState" Value="Normal"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" 
                 TargetName="WindowResizeGrip" Value="Visible"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

So I guess providing you had the Window (Shell in your case specified in a separate ResourceDictionary (XAML file) say called "CustomShellTemplateFile.xaml") you could do something like

shell.setData(
                "ResourceDictionary",
                "CustomShellTemplateFile.xaml");